# Why does my value in a pandas dataframe turns to dtype complex128 when I access it via .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

My DataFrame has a complex128 in one column. When I access another value via the .loc method it returns a complex128 instead of the stored dtype.
I encountered the problem when I was using some values from a DataFrame inside a class in a function.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [["f","i","c"],["float","int","complex"]]
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays,names=("varname","intended dtype"))
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=ind)

m1 = 1.33+1e-9j
parms1 = [1.,2,None]

a.loc["aa"] = parms1
a.loc["aa","c"] = m1

print(a.dtypes)
print(a.loc["aa","f"])
print("-----------------------------")
print(a.loc["aa",("f","float")])
print("-----------------------------")
print(a["f"])
```

If the MultiIndex is taken away that does not happen. So it seems to have some impact. But also accessing it in the MultiIndex-way does not help.
I noticed that the dtype assignment happens, because I have not specified any index in the DataFrame creation. This is necessary, because I don't know what to be filled in the beginning.

Is this a normal behavior or can I get rid of it?

pandas version is: 0.24.2
is reproducible in 0.25.3